# Local instance of SVF translator

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Is there a local version of the SVF translation process that I could use locally on my computer without having to send my design to forge platform ?
 - a standalone application under Autodesk license
 - or a revit module ?

I work on project where people do not want to send their design online but still want to use the local version of the viewer.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autodesk Forge doesn't offer a locally hosted translation service. Unfortunately, that means that if your customer is not willing to even temporarily upload their file to the Autodesk server, then they cannot use the Forge Viewer to view their files.

If your customer is ok to temporarily upload a file, then they can upload the file, translate it, download the resulting SVF, and then delete the original file. This sample on GitHub demonstrates that process - https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io.

Comment: It's actually the solution that I suggest, but it does not seem to fit in specific cases of "critical" buildings

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3ds MAX to export your files to SVF